# Python dict values to list of integers

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I'm fairly new to Python.  I have a list of dictionaries.

```
[{"x": "23"}, {"x": "14"}, {"x": "9"}, {"x": "19"}, {"x": "21"}, {"x": "14"}, {"x": "16"}, {"x": "11"}, {"x": "9"}, {"x": "6"}, {"x": "24"}, {"x": "13"}]
```

I want to extract the values associated with the `x` key and plot them.  To do that the list must look like this, and the values must be integers (or floats).

```
[23, 14, 9, 19, 21, 14, 16, 11, 9, 6, 24, 13]
```

My question is: how do I

1. extract these values, and
2. convert them to integers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using a list comprehension using the dictionary's `get` method.

```
>>> l = [{"x": "23"}, {"x": "14"}, {"x": "9"}, {"x": "19"}, {"x": "21"}, {"x": "14"}, {"x": "16"}, {"x": "11"}, {"x": "9"}, {"x": "6"}, {"x": "24"}, {"x": "13"}]
>>> [i.get('x') for i in l]
['23', '14', '9', '19', '21', '14', '16', '11', '9', '6', '24', '13']
```

If you'd like them as integers, convert them in the list comprehension

```
>>> [int(i.get('x')) for i in l]
[23, 14, 9, 19, 21, 14, 16, 11, 9, 6, 24, 13]
```

Comment: Why not `i['x']` instead of `get`?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich In this use case, that will work just fine too. I generally stick to `.get` to protect against `KeyError`, and just handle missing keys separately.

Comment: But then you need to handle getting back `None` too, otherwise you just change the exception you're getting.

Comment: Meh, just a coding preference I guess. I prefer handling it with `get` than using `try`/`except`, but whatever floats your boat :)

Comment: To me `i['x']` says "x is always present, or at least if it isn't then there's nothing we can do but crash", and `i.get('x')` says "x may not be present, and we're handling that". This question is the first case. But it's very minor of course :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). For each item get `"x"` and cast to `int`:

```
[int(item['x']) for item in mylist]
```

If you need floats change `int` to `float`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `list comprehension`

```
>>> mylist = [{'x': '23'}, {'x': '14'}, {'x': '9'}, {'x': '19'}, {'x': '21'}, {'x': '14'}, {'x': '16'}, {'x': '11'}, {'x': '9'}, {'x': '6'}, {'x': '24'}, {'x': '13'}]
>>> [ int(item.values()[0]) for item in mylist]
[23, 14, 9, 19, 21, 14, 16, 11, 9, 6, 24, 13]
```

or `map`

```
>>> map(lambda x: int(x['x']), mylist)
[23, 14, 9, 19, 21, 14, 16, 11, 9, 6, 24, 13]
```